# How to add a new column into delta table without overwrite in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I have big delta table in Azure Blob Storage Container. It stores very big size data.
Now I want to add a new column to this existing delta table. For all existing data, I want to give default value 1.
Option 1, I can read whole delta table, add new column, then overwrite. But I don't want to overwrite.
Is there other way, we can add a new column without overwrite, just give default value 1 for all existing rows?

Comment: what implementation are you using? Delta allows to add new columns with `.option("mergeSchema", "true")`, but it doesn't allow to specify default value

Answer (score 0):

You can try as below

```
df.write.format("delta").mode("append").option("mergeSchema", "true").saveAsTable("tablename")
```

Comment: it doesn't fit the requirements, as they want to set the default value for all new data